# Rails 4 - Sprockets::FileNotFound in Welcome#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts

Any ideas whats happening? I installed Highcharts in windows and worked but now in Ubuntu is not working.

This is my application.html.erb file.

```
{
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Highchartstest1</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>

}

{application.js}

{// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require highcharts
//= require_tree .
}
```

This is the example code to plot in {index.html.erb}

```
{<h1>Welcome#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>

<script> 
$(function () { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});

</script>
}

The {gemfile} is the following:

{source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  #gem 'spring'
end

}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This is also part of the error:  Showing /home/username/Schreibtisch/Rails_Projekte/highchartstest1/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

couldn't find file 'highcharts' with type 'application/javascript'

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the line `//= require highcharts` from your css manifest.

You have included the highcharts as a remote file in your application.html.erb file (`<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>`), then you shouldn't `require` it in your manifest file. That is, you're trying to require a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: I did it, it shows the welcome#index text but does not show the graph

Comment: You need to add the `container` element to your view as well. E.g. `<div id="container"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't have the js and css file of the same name. I faced this error when I had.